# node-serialport 6.x.x doesn't receive data or errors on Windows (but does on Mac)

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I am using the following library to connect via USB to an external device:

https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport

I set up the following sample project to narrow down where the issue might be:

https://github.com/nyoung697/node-serial-test

This code works on my Mac.  The device I am connecting to accepts an ascii command and the carriage return to terminate that command.

In the example project, I am passing in 'V\r' and am expecting the version of the device to be returned.  When I run this code on my Mac, I get the expected response.

However, when I run it on my Windows 10 machine, I do not get any response at all.  Neither the port.on('data') or port.on('error') events are hit.

I tested downgrading the serialport library to version 4.0.7 and it does work.

Does anyone have any ideas what might have changed between 4 => 6?

P.S. I edited this question, as I originally thought it had something to do with Electron, however after doing this simple test with only node.js, I believe I have narrowed it down to this version of the library on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I just figured this out.

All I needed to do was add the property 'rtscts' to the openOptions object I pass in to the constructor and set it to true.

```
const SERIAL_PORT_SETTINGS = {
    baudRate: 115200,
    rtscts: true
};

let port = new SerialPort(devicePath, SERIAL_PORT_SETTINGS);
```

I figured this out by digging around in the release notes.  I noticed that from v5.x.x to 6.0.0 the breaking changes included making this value default to false.

> windows: We previously hard coded to have RTS on for windows at all times it now default to off.

Comment: I just realized that setting this property to true gives me a bunch of mangled characters when I convert the buffer to string on a Mac.... haven't had a chance to debug this or figure out what rtscts actually means.  This isn't a huge priority though, as it works fine with that setting to false on Mac and true on Windows.